# An error regarding the GROUP BY clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I got this oracle error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 17
```

When ran the below query:

```
SELECT M.EMAIL, M.FNAME, M.LNAME, COUNT(*) 
FROM MEMBER M, FRIENDSHIP F  
WHERE (M.EMAIL = F.USER1 OR M.EMAIL = F.USER2 ) AND 
        F.TYPE = 'Family'
GROUP BY M.EMAIL
```

When I delete all fields except `M.EMAIL` from the `SELECT` clause it works but as soon as I add another field like `M.FNAME` get a same error!

What's going on?

Comment: Could you try `GROUP BY M.EMAIL, M.FNAME, M.LNAME` and see?

Comment: that is how groupby works. your select columns should be present in the groupby

Comment: To be clearer, all the selected columns excluding the aggregated value need to be present in the GROUP BY clause, in the same order as they appear in the SELECT clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query, It will solve your problem:)

```
  SELECT M.EMAIL, M.FNAME, M.LNAME, COUNT(*) 
  FROM MEMBER M, FRIENDSHIP F  
  WHERE (M.EMAIL = F.USER1 OR M.EMAIL = F.USER2 ) AND 
    F.TYPE = 'Family'
  GROUP BY M.EMAIL,M.FNAME,M.LNAME
```

Note: If you use aggregate functions in Select clause the we need to put all the column name in group by function except aggregate function value column.

Answer (score 2):

Put all non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` in `GROUP BY`. Also, be aware that this will eliminate all rows where the same `EMAIL` has multiple `FNAME` and `LName`. There will only be one row per email-Fname-Lname combination.

```
SELECT M.EMAIL, M.FNAME, M.LNAME, COUNT(*) 
FROM MEMBER M, FRIENDSHIP F  
WHERE (M.EMAIL = F.USER1 OR M.EMAIL = F.USER2 ) AND 
        F.TYPE = 'Family'
GROUP BY M.EMAIL, M.FNAME, M.LNAME
```